# preg_match foreach

Tags: php, regex

So I am using a preg_match to get any text after a # up until a space out of a string. However if there are multiple occasions of it in the string it will only return the first one. This is what I have so far

```
$text = '#demo1 #demo2 some text #blah2';
$check_hash = preg_match("/([#][a-zA-Z-0-9]+)/", $text, $hashtweet);
foreach ($hashtweet as $ht){
echo $ht;
}
```

The `echo $ht;` outputs `#demo1#demo1` when it should output all 3 of the words with # in front. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You want to use [`preg_match_all`](https://www.php.net/preg_match_all).

Example:

```
<?php 

$text = '#demo1 #demo2 some text #blah2';
$check_hash = preg_match_all("/([#][a-zA-Z-0-9]+)/", $text, $hashtweet);
foreach ($hashtweet[1] as $ht){
  echo $ht;
}
```

Comment: why $hashtweet[1] use index [1]? not just $hashtweet? I tried using index [0] the results is the same

Answer (score 1):

Check [preg_match_all](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)